# How can I book a flight after getting flight refund they won't let me

Tags: usa

I booked a flight using a 3rd party aggregator - cheapoair. There was a snafu at their end and I got double charged for the ticket.

They initiated a refund withe the airline and I got my money back. However when I try to book the same itenary, I'm unable to do so. I believe it's because the airlines has a record of me cancelling a previous reservation.

How do I get around this and rebook the original itenary?

Comment: Are you trying to book through the same 3rd party, or direct with the airline?

Comment: Was the refund for the full double charge, or just for the extra amount you were charged in error?